# Trying to get my app to print out two lines of text from a file

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get my android app to print out two lines of text from my file but it will not work. Can anybody see why?

Here is my java code
    package com.example.fileio.app1_fileio;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   // String name = "";

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



    try {
        // open the file for reading
        InputStream fis = new FileInputStream("android.txt");

        // if file the available for reading
        if (fis != null) {

            // prepare the file for reading
            InputStreamReader chapterReader = new InputStreamReader(fis);
            BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(chapterReader);

            String line;

            // read every line of the file into the line-variable, on line at the time


//I THINK THE PROBLEM LIES HERE
            do {
                line = buffreader.readLine();
                // do something with the line
                System.out.println(line);

                //get a reference to the textview in the view, this is done by referring to the textview's id: outputText
                TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textField);

                //overwrite the text in the textview
                t.setText(line);

            } while (line != null);

        }

        fis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // print stack trace.
    }



    //determine a name for the file we are going to write
    String fileName = "test_file.txt";

    //create a new file using the utility class: "FileUtility"
    FileUtility myFile = new FileUtility();

    Log.i("Info", "Android File Example Main Activity Completed");

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

I think the problem lies in the do part of my try catch.

The xml is:

```
<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textField" />
```

Comment: the problem is here `InputStream fis = new FileInputStream("android.txt");` is probably throwing `FileNotFoundException `, but we will never know, becuase you catch block is empty!!!!1!

Comment: The path to the file is right, I just changed it when posted here.

Comment: but what's the issue? What's not working ?

Comment: It just won't print to the output of the text field in the android app. It should print from the text file, but it won't.

Comment: t.setText(line); should overwrite the text field.

Comment: is `System.out.println(line);` outputting something ?

Comment: put `e.printStackTrace()` in catch block!